# Custom error message on failed authentication in IdentityServer4

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I would like to display custom error message when authentication fails in IdentityServer4. Namely I want to show what went wrong, e.g. "invalid redirect url" or "invalid authentication flow". When authentication fails I see only that exception occured but for what happened I need to go into logs. In this case I would like to know that e.g. redirect url is wrong directly. How can I achieve that?

I'm thinking about some exception filter or custom middleware on ASP.NET Core. However it seems to me that exception filter won't work since that is MVC stuff and exception occurs in the IdentityServer middleware. And I am not sure how to create the middleware so it shows the error and also manages to use the same layout and ui parts as in MVC views. Is there another way? Maybe some extension points I did not see?

Comment: You really shouldn't be passing that detail around as it reveals information about the system to users and lowers the security.

Comment: I was thinking about that but I would not like to reveal all information. However in some cases it would help to know that I have another application which has only bad configuration (hence the example with invalid redirect uri). I also saw that attitude in Microsoft login workflow and it helped me quite a lot. Is that such a security issue?

Comment: @JindřichPergler I have the same requirement, I need to have custom response when authentication fails, did you by any chance find extension point?

Comment: @DarjanBogdan No, I did not solve this and got used to finding the information in the logs.